How do I change the company logo in the banner at the top of the screen which appears on every page of my website?
We recently changed our company name and logo. The old logo is on the middle of EVERY page in the middle of the banner (along with other options to the left and right which allow you to choose various pages). I cannot figure out how to change the logo in the banner to our new logo. Help. I cannot even see where it was ever defined in the first place.

Drupal  7.94, CKEditor 4.14.0, database system version 5.5.30.

Depending on how your site is setup and which version of drupal it's built on, you'll most likely find the logo on the active theme's settings:

Click on "Appearance" on Admin Toolbar.

Find the theme that has "(default theme)" next to it's name. It's going to be the first theme listed. Screenshot below.

Click on "Settings" for this theme.

Find the setting for "Logo image" and upload a new logo


You should probably download a copy of the current logo image in case uploading your new logo messes with the design layout.
There is a chance that the Theme settings for your site are overridden somewhere else too, and this won't work.
Here's a screenshot of finding the current active theme from step 3:


I followed your steps listed but it did not change the logo. I think what I am needing to update is within the "titles for page"..
